# Help finding small faucet aerator

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

[image]Can anyone suggest where I can find an aerator like the attached?  The faucet is made by the Rubinet Faucet Co. but I cannot get through to them.  The aerator has an M16.5 male thread.  All aerators that I can see have the thread at the bottom, rather than the top.

Comment: Seems like you're missing some of the parts perhaps? It doesn't look like that tool has anything to match up to for loosening/tightening the aerator.

Comment: Rubinet's [Contacts Page](https://www.rubinet.com/contact-us) has four methods of contact. Are telephone, fax, email and web-based messaging all non-responsive? The Contacts page also has a "Where to Buy" link that should lead you to Rubinet retailers so you could ask in person.